# Product object is empty even after assigning it a value

Tags: c#, class

I have a static class (`Argus`) with a property called `myArgus` which is a List, and a separate form called `EditProduct`. Within the constructor of `EditProduct`, I have this line:

```
// Make a copy of the product so we can easily reference it in this class
product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]._categoryProducts[prodIndex];
```

I'm doing this so I can just use `product._productName;` in my code rather than this:

`Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]._categoryProducts[prodIndex]._productName;`

At the top of the `EditProduct` form I'm defining this property:

`Product product = new Product();`

Then, later in the `EditProduct` class, I'm doing this:

```
txtName.Text = product._productName;
txtDetails.Text = product._productDetails;
txtPrice.Text = product._productPrice.ToString();
txtStock.Text = product._productStockLevel.ToString();
pbProduct.ImageLocation = product._productPicLoc;
```

However, none of the fields on the form actually populate. Using a breakpoint, I found out that `product` is empty (it contains empty strings and 0 for integer/double values). I have verified that I'm pointing to a valid product when I assign it. I get no errors, and no clue as to why `product` is blank. :|

Here's the full class if it helps:

http://pastebin.com/fFDq8GxU

What could be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Beware of Static!
"Static member of a class is shared by all instances of the class."
Aren't you elsewhere defining the values?

Comment: @PedroFerreira: I don't see anything static in that class.

Comment: "I have a static class (Argus) with a property called myArgus"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your constructor:

```
populateFields();

... 

// Make a copy of the product so we can easily reference it in this class
product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]
    ._categoryProducts[prodIndex];
```

So you're setting the `product` variable *after* you've used it in `populateFields`. That's not going to work...

I would actually suggest that you don't even use an instance variable here unless you really need to. I would change the constructor to...

```
// Ideally you should simplify this...
Product product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]
    ._categoryProducts[prodIndex];
PopulateFields(product);
```

And change your method to take a parameter:

```
private void PopulateFields(Product product)
{
    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, you're not using `product` anywhere else, and you're not calling `populateFields` except in the constructor - so you don't really need it to be part of the state of your object.

Comment: Oh Jesus. Now I feel like a fool. I'll put that one down as a brain fart. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `populateFields` before you assign a value to `product`.
Change your constructor to this:

```
public EditProduct(int catIndex, int prodIndex)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.catIndex = catIndex;
    this.prodIndex = prodIndex;

    // Create file handler
    fileHandler = new FileHandler(Argus.dataFileLoc);

    // Make a copy of the product so we can easily reference it in this class
    product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]
                                              ._categoryProducts[prodIndex];

    // This must be called after the previous line!
    populateFields();
}
```

Comment: Also, the EditProduct class won't need `new Product()` in the declaration of the `product` member, because the constructor is always assigning that a different value anyway. It can just be declared as `Product product;`

Answer (score 0):

You call to *populateFields* before you put the value into product.

this is wrong:

```
            populateFields();

        // Create file handler
        fileHandler = new FileHandler(Argus.dataFileLoc);

        // Make a copy of the product so we can easily reference it in this class
        product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]._categoryProducts[prodIndex];
```

this will work:

```
            // Make a copy of the product so we can easily reference it in this class
        product = Argus.myArgus[Argus.branchIndex]._branchCategories[catIndex]._categoryProducts[prodIndex];

            populateFields();

        // Create file handler
        fileHandler = new FileHandler(Argus.dataFileLoc);
```